# Espresso Store - How to build a list of orders between two dates?

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

We've built a custom report for a customer using Espresso Store2, And we'd like to add the ability to allow the the user to select a start and end date to filter orders. Is this possible using expresso store alone, or do we need to also make use of a third party plugin?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting these reports via the front or back end?

Comment: Sadly expresso store built in reports don't provide the flexibility of what we need, so the report we have built is a custom fronted template page, that's limited so only site admin's can view. So front end in that sense.